# How can I disable the Option+click hiding behaviour?

Tags: macos, finder

In Mac OS X Mountain Lion at least, if you <kbd>Option</kbd>+click ( <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click ) on another a window of another app, this will make the other application to gain focus, and the current app to be *hidden* as if you'd pressed <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Is there any way to disable this behaviour? Perhaps with some `defaults write` like command entered in a terminal?

I'd like to use <kbd>Option</kbd>+click for some different behaviour (moving windows by <kbd>Option</kbd>+clicking anywhere on them, using a third-party tool, Zoom2), and having <kbd>Option</kbd>+click trigger the hiding behaviour instead is very inconvenient.

Comment: You could just use a different shortcut in Zoom2 :)

Comment: Possibly, but it's hard to find some combination that doesn't have some undocumented side-effect in Mac OS X, or doesn't require a silly number of meta keys. Obviously control+click is right out. Shift+click is occasionally useful, and command+click sometimes means things in certain apps. What would you suggest?

Comment: Do you use a two-button mouse?  Maybe option-right click.

Comment: And if you use a trackpad/magic mouse, you could use some kind of gesture, like three finger tap. BetterTouchTool has awesome support for this sort of thing (and actually I think might even support this exact feature).

Comment: I use a Logitech mouse with about 7 buttons. And I have used USB Overdrive to map a couple of those to the modifier key and click. But when I'm using my MacBook without the mouse plugged in, I still want some usable set of modifiers I can use with my trackpad to move/resize windows.

Comment: So, the workaround I'm using is to use `Command`+click instead of `Option`+click for the window moving. But for the reference of other users, I'm leaving the question unanswered, as there doesn't seem to be a way to disable the `option`-click hiding, which other users may want for other reasons.

Comment: Wait, my windows hiding themselves is a _feature_?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no way to disable this behavior. You can <kbd>command</kbd>-click to manipulate any window in the background without focusing it or bringing it to the front. (This has been around since classic Mac OS.) You can indeed combine <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd> to <kbd>alt</kbd>-click a window item in the background without triggering the application hiding.

Comment: Command-Option-Click on something in a background app *does* often hide the app in front. Example: with Safari in front, Command-Option-Click the checkbox of a calendar in Calendar; Safari is hidden and Calendar comes to front.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-SW15 observes: "If the user presses the Command key while dragging an inactive window, the window moves, but does not become active.".

Comment: `command`+click dragging on the title bar of an inactive window will move it without making it active, but if I add `otpion` it does trigger the unwanted hiding behaviour.

Comment: option-klicking a windwow's title bar doesn't have any standard functionality, so it doesn't make sense to do this. With window-item I meany any widget within that window, like buttons.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to remap Option+Left Click to something else using [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/).  It might not have exactly what you want, but I think it's not hard to add new shortcuts (or ask the author to add them for you).  One option that I saw was Option+Left Click -> Middle Click.  You could then (assumedly) set middle click to do what you want in Zoom2, and retain the Option+Click shortcut.

Of course, if you do this, it will change Option+Click everywhere, even if you aren't clicking on another window.

Comment: The downside of that, without contacting the KeyRemap4MacBook developer, is that I can't use middle click for anything else (eg opening new tabs in a browser). Unless I use KeyRemap4MacBook to remap _actual_ middle-click to-- oh god, no.

Comment: Supposedly, you can add any mapping you want just by editing some xml file or something.  I've never actually tried it myself, so I can't say how hard it is.  I have contacted the developer before, though, and he seems to be friendly enough.