# How to override default `Modifier key + Click on app icon in Dock` behaviour on macOS?

Tags: macos, applications, dock, keybindings, defaults

For example, by default <kbd>Option(Alt)</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> on application icon in Dock hides all windows of currently active application. And <kbd>Option(Alt)</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> hides all applications, except for one which's icon was clicked.

Is it possible to override <kbd>Modifier key</kbd> + <kbd>Click on app icon in Dock</kbd> behaviour to, for example, minimising windows of application which's icon was clicked or opening a new window for it with let's say <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> on its icon?

My question is quite similar to [this one from 8 years ago](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71307/how-can-i-disable-the-optionclick-hiding-behaviour), but it seems there was no resolution at that time.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? You can act on a non-focussed window by holding Cmd as you do it. It will not bring the window or app forwards, simply act on it. You can always minimise the current window with CMd/M, or the yellow dot, or double-click the title bar (Dock prefs)

Comment: Right now I want to be able to open a new window when I click on safari or another browser in dock. However, overriding modifier key + click behaviours might be really useful in general

Comment: Opening a new window from the Dock is already possible. Right click (or Ctrl/click) the Dock icon & there it is. Overriding global system behaviour is inadvisable.

Comment: I know that I can do it like this, but it requires two clicks and also navigating to appropriate item in the menu that pops up. My workflow requires opening new windows quite often, thus the amount of time I can safe by eliminating second click is considerable. Also I am totally fine with overriding global system behaviour

Comment: So… that is the question you should have asked. What we have right now is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: I believe you are right in a way, my apologies for being unclear. However, as I said above, it is also a question of `overriding modifier key + click behaviours` in general, so that I could also assign other actions to them, like minimising a window or quitting an application with a particular `modifier key + click on the dock icon`

Comment: It's still inadvisable to try override global behaviour, especially for something as trivial as 'New Window' which is Cmd/N in almost everything. btw, your initial premise is wrong. Opt/clicking an app in the dock hides only the app that was currently frontmost. Cmd/opt/click hides all. Ctrl/click is the universal shortcut for right-click.

Comment: Very true, regarding default behaviour of option + click. It's Cmd+N only when application is active, while I want to open new window especially when it is not. And it really worths overriding defaults in my situation. Apart from that my question is more about overriding these defaults, not opening new window, which I could implement simply with an automation assigned to a shortcut

Comment: You really need to condense all this into one solid, properly researched question, not just in a series of comments. The answer is still going to be "You really, really don't want to do it that way" but at least it will be answerable. So far, this isn't.